# Change what bucket elastic beanstalk uploads to on eb deploy?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there a way to change which bucket elastic beanstalk uploads too when I run the command

```
eb deploy
```

currently it uploads to this bucket

```
elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I have a web tier and a worker tier environment

Answer (score 0):

The bucket specified for an elastic beanstalk will exist in the policy that specifies the bucket access, to know which policy it is, you have to go to the role that you have selected when configuring the elastic beanstalk.

in the AWS management console, under "Security and Identity" select "Identity and Access Management", under "Roles" select the role that you selected during your beanstalk configuration, check the policies assigned to that role you must see a policy similar to :

```
   {

  "Sid": "BucketAccess",
  "Action": [
    "s3:Get*",
    "s3:List*",
    "s3:PutObject"
            ],
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-*",
    "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-*/*"
              ]

   }
```

as seen in the json above, the bucket name will be elasticbeanstalk-*, where aws appends your beanstalk region along with an identifier.